# Scala Macros: How to create setter function for case classes

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I would like to use macro to generate a setter for case classes. e.g:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

Macro.mkSetter[Person, String]("name") : Person => String => Person
```

I tried the following implementation but I keep getting the following

`error: scala: Error: Unknown source file: embeddedFile--QuasiquoteCompat.scala@6....`

(I am using scala 2.10.3 with macro-paradise 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT)

```
object Macro {

  def mkSetter[A, B](fieldName: String): (A,B) => A = macro mkSetter_impl[A,B]

  def mkSetter_impl[A: c.WeakTypeTag, B: c.WeakTypeTag](c : Context)(fieldName: c.Expr[String]): c.Expr[(A,B) => A] = {
    import c.universe._
    val (aTpe, bTpe) =  (weakTypeOf[A], weakTypeOf[B])

    val constructor = aTpe.declarations.collectFirst {
      case m: MethodSymbol if m.isPrimaryConstructor => m
    }.getOrElse(c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"Cannot find constructor in ${weakTypeOf[A]}"))

    val field = constructor.paramss.head.find(
      _.name.decoded == fieldName.toString()
    ).getOrElse(c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"Cannot find constructor field named in $fieldName"))

    c.Expr[(A,B) => A](q"{(a: $aTpe, b: $bTpe) => a.copy(${field.name} = b)}")
  }
}
```

I do realise that `_.name.decoded == fieldName.toString()` is not correct way to check method name (even if `_.name.decoded == "name"` seems to be ok)

*Bonus point:* generalise macro with varags parameters for parameters with same type, e.g.

```
 def mkSetter[A, B](fieldNames: String*): A => B => B ... => A = macro mkSetter_impl[A,B]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Could you provide more details about your environment, e.g. post a project at github? The issue you're facing seems to be unrelated to the macro that you're trying to write. I've been able to run it successfully with just a couple of minor changes.

Comment: Thank you @EugeneBurmako. Here is the [project](https://github.com/julien-truffaut/Lens/blob/macro/macros/src/main/scala/lens/Macro.scala) I am working on.

Comment: `sbt compile` and `sbt test` are both okay. Do I need to do something special to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I added some [macro tests](https://github.com/julien-truffaut/Lens/blob/macro/examples/src/test/scala/MacroSpec.scala) that passes with sbt. However, I get the same error than before with intellij (Community edition v 13.0.1) when I try to run the same tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be caused by https://github.com/scalamacros/paradise/issues/11. This week I planned to fix that issue, so it should be fine soon. You could subscribe to updates at scalamacros.org (http://scalamacros.org/news/rss.xml) or follow me on Twitter to get notified when the fix is deployed.